# Is there a way I can query sql/ sequelize by percentage weighting

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a `post` table, a `shares` table and a `likes` table. `Likes` and `Shares` table have a **belongTo** relationship with a `Post` table.

I am trying to query results so that 75% of the results are ordered by the amount of shares the post has and 25% the amount of likes the post has

```
  const feed = await postsModel.findAll({
      
      order: [['numShares', 'desc'], ['numLikes', 'desc']],
      limit: limit,

    })
```

Comment: where do `numShares` and `numLikes` come from?

Comment: I created a count column for both in the post table

Comment: I think you’ll need to update your question to show a minimal reproducible example e.g. table ddl, sample data and the result you want to achieve